# Automate az container exec

Tags: bash, ubuntu, azure-cli

AZ CLI supports executing a **single** command in a running container.

`az container exec -g myresourcegroup -n nginxtest --exec-command /bin/bash`

Because of this, you cannot automate running multiple commands over existing container directly as you can with docker.

Is it possible to go around this with `stdin, stdout, stderr` redirection or multiplexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned how to do it with the `screen` multiplexer!

### Setup

`sudo screen -S azexec -dmL bash`

- This creates a new detached terminal running bash with name `azexec`
- The `-L` argument makes all output to be be saved into a file `screenlog.0`
- The `-d` argument makes the terminal detached
- Right now it just starts a new bash terminal

`sudo screen -S azexec -p 0 -X stuff "az container exec -g myresourcegroup -n nginxtest --exec-command /bin/bash^M"`

- You send `az container exec` and after some time, the detached terminal switches to the container terminal
- If you are trying to automate this, you need to `sleep` for some time to let the `az` command enter before running any other

### Run any commands

`sudo screen -S azexec -p 0 -X stuff "ANY_COMMAND^M"`

- don't forget the `stuff` keyword
- don't forget to add `^M` at the end of your commands, it simulates the enter key

#### Warning

- When using a multiplexer you have the control over the terminal, not over the commands that you run inside the terminal. You need to `sleep` or handle completion of your commands some other way.
- If you just installed `screen` then you will not see the `az` package installed in its terminal. But after you install it once in the screen terminal with `apt` it stays there. It should be trivial to automate that process.
- You also need to `az login` with `--service-principal` if you want to automate this with Azure Pipelines
- I wrote a complete script to run in Azure Pipelines here: https://github.com/czmirek/stuff/blob/master/azexecmultiple/script.sh

Answer (score 1):

As you know the command `az container exec` only supports single command. And it seems the stdin, stdout, stderr you use as `< testpipe >/dev/null 2>&1 &` is also an input, so when you use it with the command `/bin/bash`, it's a multiple-parameter command. Of course, it will not work.

Azure Container Instance just provides a fast running feature, but it does not support much control well. So if you want to have more control with the container, I recommend you use the AKS or configure a Docker server in the VM directly. These two ways will let you have more control over the containers.